# Using .Net API Client for Mobile devices

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Can I use Rest client or .NET client libraries for the YT data API V3 and publish on Android and iOS platforms? OR I need to use specific libraries for each platform?

In simple text, I mean, Am I allowed to use any client library and publish on Mobile platform?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking if you can write .NET to deploy to iOS and Android devices?  There are cross-platform solutions such as Xamarin Studio.

Comment: Yes. I saw in documentation asking for mobile platform build identifier and other info. Consider im using xamarin, am i allowed to publish on ios n android with .net api for youtube?